# Regarding CPU utilization

Tags: c, macos

Considering the below piece of C code, I expected the CPU utilization to go up to 100% as the processor would try to complete the job (endless in this case) given to it. On running the executable for 5 mins, I found the CPU to go up to a max. of 48%. I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8; processor: Intel Core 2 Duo; Compiler: GCC 4.1.

```
int i = 10;
while(1) {
    i = i * 5;
}
```

Could someone please explain why the CPU usage does not go up to 100%? Does the OS limit the CPU from reaching 100%?

Please note that if I added a "printf()" inside the loop the CPU hits 88%. I understand that in this case, the processor also has to write to the standard output stream hence the sharp rise in usage.

Has this got something to do with the amount of job assigned to the processor per unit time?

Regards,
Ven.

Answer (score 2):

You have a multicore processor and you are in a single thread scenario, so you will use only one core full throttle ... Why do you expect the overall processor use go to 100% in a similar context ?

Answer (score 0):

Run two copies of your program at the same time. These will use both cores of your "Core 2 Duo" CPU and overall CPU usage will go to 100%

---

**Edit**

> if I added a "printf()" inside the loop the CPU hits 88%.

The printf send some characters to the terminal/screen. Sending information, Display and Update is handeled by code outside your exe, this is likely to be executed on another thread. But displaying a few characters does not need 100% of such a thread. That is why you see 100% for Core 1 and 76% for Core 2 which results in the overal CPU usage of 88% what you see.

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure you'll see 100% _most_ of the time

Comment: Don't know, didn't try. OP said with printf it goes to 88% indicating it might use two CPUs already

Comment: It goes to 88% when I add a "printf("%s", "whatever")" in the loop. So, would I be correct in saying that if number of thread >= number of CPU cores, the CPU utilization would hit 100% (provided the job takes a measurable amount of time to complete)?

Comment: @Ven did you run two copies of your program simultaneously? See my Edit for the printf

Comment: @DrKoch: Yes I did. CPU utilization goes up to 100% (both cores at max)